# why in the for loop in the example below the result isn't the same exactly in the second for loop in each of the two examples

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

Alliteration refers to a sequence of words that begin with the same letter. For this exercise, a sentence is correctly alliterated if all words strictly greater than 3 characters begin with the same letter.

Examples:

```
alliteration_correct("She swam to the shore.") ➞ True
# All words >= 4 letters long begins with "s"

alliteration_correct("Maybel manages money well.") ➞ False
# "well" does not begin with an "m"

alliteration_correct("He helps harness happiness.") ➞ True

alliteration_correct("There are many animals.") ➞ False
```

Notes:

```
def alliteration_correct(sentence):
    sentence = sentence.split(" ")
    ll = []
    for i in sentence:
        if len(i) > 3:
            ll.append(i)
    for x in ll:
        if x.lower()[0] == ll[0][0].lower():
            return True
    return False


print(alliteration_correct("He helps harness happiness."))

print(alliteration_correct("There are many animals."))
```

```
def alliteration_correct(sentence):
    sentence = sentence.split(" ")
    ll = []
    for i in sentence:
        if len(i) > 3:
            ll.append(i)
    for x in ll:
        if x.lower()[0] != ll[0][0].lower():
            return False
    return True


print(alliteration_correct("He helps harness happiness."))

print(alliteration_correct("There are many animals."))
```

Comment: Returning `True` on first successful match in a loop is **not** the same thing as returning `False` on first failed match.

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to be doing is check for the occurrence of first character of the words with length greater than 3.

The case where you return false for a mismatch is valid as you don't need to check any further, and you return false simply.
But in the opposite returning true for just making a check for the first word of length > 3, is not valid.

This makes logic different.
Hope it helps.